# How to capture a keyboard shortcut

Tags: x11, keyboard, input

I need a script, that will run in terminal (under X11), and wait for a keyboard shortcut (happening anywhere in the desktop environment), once that shortcut (or key press sequence) happens, it will terminate with return code = 0.

PS: I need this to tell byzanz when to stop recording my desktop.

Possible candidates to use in that script are `xev` and `xinput` but I can't figure out how to put things together. Ie. `xinput` seems promising, but it's making me specify the device, which I want to happen automatically, and I don't know how to use it in a script that will terminate once a sequence on the output is found.

Comment: You **might** try looking at Tk and some of the options it has. Basically you'll need to perform a passive grab for the keyboard shortcut in question. I don't know of any existing utility that'll do that, so it may come down to writing a short utility in C that will do what you want, or find a scripting language with GUI support, like Tk. **Disclaimer**: I've never worked with Tk, so I don't know if it'll do what you need or not.

Answer (score 1):

`xinput test-xi2 --root` captures events from all sources. You will receive 4 events - `RawKeyPress`, `KeyPress`, `RawKeyRelease` and `KeyRelease`, all containing the keycode in `detail:` section. I'm not sure whether you should use raw events or not, but when you listen to mouse events, relying on raw events is required in case of other program grabbing the device with `owner_events = 1` ([XGrabPointer](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGrabPointer.html) or [XIGrabDevice](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-XIGrabDevice/)), so unless you need Xserver to track modifiers for you, I would recommend using raw events.

I once wrote a program that captured keyboard and mouse events - https://github.com/pzmarzly/x11-input-mirror

EDIT: from what I've tested, raw events behave in an opposite way for keyboard events. So for the highest success rate, grab raw mouse events, but non-raw keyboard events.