# How to capture all keyinput directly to a terminal app

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard

I'm creating a simple terminal app to help teach keyboard shortcuts (using ruby/curses and running *Manjaro* and *i3*).

Let's say a shortcut I'm trying to learn is `S-Return` for **open a new terminal**.

I want the app to show the prompt `Open new terminal`, I then type in `S-Return` and the app gives me a big old tick of approval.

The problem is - when I enter `S-Return` *i3* intercepts it and just opens a new terminal window. I have the same issue if it's a keyboard shortcut set within the terminal I am running the app in.

Is there a way to (temporarily) reroute all keyboard input directly to the terminal app? Ideally I'd like this to work not just for *Manjaro*/*i3* but across different distros.

TIA.

Comment: That's going to be specific to a given application, e.g., a particular terminal emulator, and some won't support this.

Comment: I see. Do you know of any emulator that does support it? What would the feature be called?

Comment: If you don't have a name for this yet, I think `i3tutor` would be fitting :)

Comment: Start [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=x11+grab+keyboard&ei=cVebYq2fH7OIwbkPl_megAg&oq=x11+grab+&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMggIABAeEBYQCjIGCAAQHhAWMgUIABCGAzoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFD3CVj3CWD1HGgBcAF4AIABP4gBP5IBATGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) something like [xinput](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179901/how-to-capture-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: However, see [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1285770)